Invalid python interpreter selected in HPC
I interact with the HPC of my workplace via VScode, and my company’s HPC system uses Linux, so my terminal is in Bash. For my projects, I created a custom environment (call it environment RE). The python version associated with RE is 3.11.9. Somehow, after creating it I received the error “an invalid Python interpreter is selected”. I went to terminal with “python —version” and it shows 3.11.9. However, when I went to the environment interpreter via Ctrl + Shift + P, it shows that the Python version associated with RE (the path to RE is correct) is 3.1.x. I uninstalled RE, cleared cache (python debugger: clear cache and reload window), re-installed it, and manually put the path of RE into the environment interpreter, and this time it shows the right Python version of 3.11.9.
However, when I turned off my computer, turned it on again, and re-opened to my HPC account, the Python version in the environment interpreter had reverted back to 3.1.x. I basically can re-do everything again: uninstall RE, clear cache, reinstall RE, manually put RE path in interpreter, but I really don’t want to do it every time I open my HPC account. Why does this mismatch keep happening? Is there a way to fix it? Are there deep issues that I shoud look into?
What I tried: Uninstall custom environment, clear cache, reinstall custom environment, manually put the environment’s path in the environment interpreter.
